# Subset a dataframe by unique combination of values from another dataframe in R

Tags: r, coordinates, subset

I have a large dataframe A similar to the following and a second one, B, containing only lat/lon values. 
What I am trying to do is to subset dataframe A based on the unique combinations of lat/lon from dataframe B. 
So far, I have tried the following but does not work. 
How should I change my code in order to effectively do this?

```
head(A)
  vals       time     lon  lat mo year
1        5 1978-11-01 100 32    01 1988
2        3 1978-11-02 100 45    02 1988
3        3 1978-11-03 100 45    01 1998
4        9 1978-11-04 100 50    05 1998
5        1 1978-11-05 100 60    05 1998
6        4 1978-11-06 100 32    05 1998



A_subset <-subset(A, A[, "lon"] %in% B$lon | A[, "lat"]
                 %in% B$lat)
```

Comment: Unique combinations across two columns would return more than one value. Do you expect only one subset?

Comment: @Parfait what I want to do is to subset dataframe A with my points (lat/lon values) from dataset B. I thought that I could do this with  one subset, but if that is not the case, my thought is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider running an `expand.grid` on data frame B for all combination of unique coordinates. Then merge to data frame A:

```
B_all_combns <- expand.grid(lon = unique(B$lon), lat = unique(B$lat))

A_subset <- merge(A, B_all_combns, by=c("lon", "lat"))
```